# BluetoothSocket Timeout or readline timeout

Tags: android, bluetooth, timeout, inputstream, readline

I am currently working on an application that talks to a serial device via bluetooth.  I have it implemented in a way that opens the connection to the bluetooth device.  It seems like it connects fine.  When it performs the reader.readline() it seems like it hangs.  It never comes back.  The device itself comes back with the following when it responds.

RD,97,101,100,41613,3000,3,0,153,153,4120,161,4,0,97,102,103,220,20,493,4568,3
000,100,0,100,5,

which is what I am expecting back.  However I need to time out the reader.rea

```
package com.clarke.android.smartflow;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.http.util.EncodingUtils;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;

import com.xyx.android.activity.Main;
import com.xyx.android.errors.ErrorService;
import com.xyx.android.events.EventDeviceDetail;


public class SmartFlowService {

    private static final String CLASSTAG = SmartFlowService.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String DEVICE_NAME = "FireFlyBP"; //FireFlyBP-70D0


    private static BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
    private static BufferedWriter writer = null;
    private static BufferedReader reader = null;
    private static BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    private static BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = null;      
    private static boolean isConnected = false;
    static Handler mSendHandler = new Handler(); 

    private InputStream mmInStream;

    //private final OutputStream mmOutStream;


    private static ArrayList<SmartFlowListener> listeners = new ArrayList<SmartFlowListener>();

    public static void addSmartFlowListener(SmartFlowListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public static void removeSmartFlowListener(SmartFlowListener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    private static void fireSmartFlowEvent(EventDeviceDetail eventDeviceDetail) {
        SmartFlowEvent smartFlowEvent = new SmartFlowEvent(SmartFlowService.class, eventDeviceDetail);
        for (Iterator<SmartFlowListener> iterator = listeners.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            SmartFlowListener listener = iterator.next();
            listener.onSmartFlowEvent(smartFlowEvent);
        }
    }

    public static void connect() throws Exception {
        Log.d(Main.LOGTAG, CLASSTAG +" connect");


        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        for (Iterator<BluetoothDevice> iterator = pairedDevices.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            BluetoothDevice bd = iterator.next();
            Log.d(Main.LOGTAG, CLASSTAG +" found device "+ bd.getName());
            if (bd.getName().startsWith(DEVICE_NAME)) {
                Log.d(Main.LOGTAG, CLASSTAG +" using device "+ bd.getName() +" "+ bd.getBluetoothClass().toString());
                bluetoothDevice = bd;
            }
        }


        if (bluetoothDevice != null) { 
            //socket = bd.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(java.util.UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
            Method m = bluetoothDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class}); 
            bluetoothSocket = (BluetoothSocket)m.invoke(bluetoothDevice, Integer.valueOf(1));
            bluetoothSocket.connect();
            isConnected = true;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Could not find bluetooth device");
        }
    }

    public static String sendR() throws Exception {

        return send("R");
    }

    public static String sendS(Integer targetRate, Integer pcOffCode) throws Exception {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("S,");
        if (targetRate != null) {
            sb.append(targetRate);
            sb.append(",");
        }
        if (pcOffCode != null) {
            sb.append(pcOffCode);
        }
        sb.append("\r\n");
        return send(sb.toString());
    }

    public static String send(String request) throws Exception {
        Log.d(Main.LOGTAG, CLASSTAG +" send");
        String response = null;
        InputStream mmInStream;
        StringBuilder swriter = new StringBuilder();
        //int swriter = 0;

        try {
            connect();
            if (isConnected) {
                writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream()));
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bluetoothSocket.getInputStream()));

                writer.write(request);
                writer.flush();

                response = reader.readLine();
                // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
                fireSmartFlowEvent(new EventDeviceDetail(response));
                Log.d(Main.LOGTAG, CLASSTAG +" send "+ response);
                Log.d(Main.LOGTAG, CLASSTAG +" send "+ response);
                bluetoothSocket.close();
                isConnected=false;
            } else {
                throw new Exception("No Bluetooth connection");
            }                           
            //bluetoothSocket.close();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(Main.LOGTAG, CLASSTAG +" send", e);
            fireSmartFlowEvent(new EventDeviceDetail(e));           
            isConnected = false; //force a reconnection retry
            throw e;
        }
        return response;
    }

    public static void close() {
        Log.d(Main.LOGTAG, CLASSTAG +" close");
        try
        {
            if (writer != null) { writer.close(); }
            if (reader != null) { reader.close(); }
            if (bluetoothSocket != null) { bluetoothSocket.close(); }
            isConnected = false;
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            Log.d(Main.LOGTAG, CLASSTAG +" close", t);
            ErrorService.log(t);
        }
    }
}
```